# Send date and time for method post

Tags: php, arrays, date, datetime, post

I send a var type DATETIME in a form with method POST , the format of the date is "2014-04-20 05:00:47" but when is recived for boleta.php this show only "2014-04-20". I dont understand, i posted the code php/html and code of boleta.php

code html/php:

```
<?php $var=array();

?>
<?php foreach ($model as $data): ?>
    <h1> <?php $var[]= $data->fecha_ingreso;

    ?></h1>
    <?php endforeach?>

      <form action="boleta.php" method="POST" class="form-horizontal" role="form">



<label for="fecha">Select date</label><br>
  <select name="fecha" class="form-control">
    <option value = <?php echo $var[0]; ?> >   <?php echo $var[0];?>  </option>
    <option value = <?php echo $var[1]; ?> >    <?php echo $var[1];?>  </option>
    <option value = <?php echo $var[2]; ?> >    <?php echo $var[2];?>  </option>

  </select> 
 <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
              <div class="pull-right">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

         </form>
```

code boleta.php

<?php

date_default_timezone_set("America/Santiago");

echo $_POST['fecha'];
?>

Comment: can you please provide a screenshot of your database table?

Comment: the user S.Scherhak send me the solution. Thx sahadat! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set your options value into " from ...

```
<option value = <?php echo $var[0]; ?> >
```

to

```
<option value = "<?php echo $var[0]; ?>" >
```

Maybe thats the solution

Comment: Fine ... please mark it left hand as the solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you datetime array build correctly. you just add " both side to option value assign variable like this `<option value = "<?php echo $var[0]; ?>" >`. I have test this sample html and works for me.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>

    <form action="boleta.php" method="POST" class="form-horizontal" role="form">

        <label for="fecha">Select date</label><br>
        <select name="fecha" class="form-control">
            <option value='2014-04-20 05:00:47'>'2014-04-20 05:00:47'</option>
            <option value='2014-04-21 05:00:47'>2014-04-21 05:00:47</option>
            <option value='2014-04-22 05:00:47'>2014-04-22 05:00:47</option>

        </select>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                <div class="pull-right">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope that it helps you.